# Formulae distinguished only by case

Tags: notation

A recent question (on $\ce{CI}$ v $\ce{Cl}$) reminded of this question: are there any real (as opposed to contrived) formulae which would be the same if case was ignored?

One certain example is $\ce{Co}$, Cobalt, and $\ce{CO}$, Carbon Monoxide.  Of course, confusing Cobalt and Carbon Monoxide is rather unlikely.

In my search for others, the best example I could find was $\ce{BaS}$, Barium Sulphide, and $\ce{BAs}$, Boron Arsenide.  Are these real substances and is the stoichiometry just $1:1$?  I had trouble verifying that.

Are there any more interesting examples?

One real example that I saw once was a poster in a university chemistry lab showing some complex organic molecules.  $\ce{Ac}$ appeared at many points but it seemed very unlikely that these compounds contained Actinium.  I then noticed $\ce{Me}$ and $\ce{Et}$ and guessed that they were organic units e.g. methyl and ethyl so $\ce{Ac}$ may have been acetyl.

Comment: Well, this is a legitimate concern indeed, which is why we feel irate to no end when somebody messes up cases in chemical formulae.

Comment: BaS is indeed a known compound, with the NaCl prototype. BAs is also a known compound with the ZnS prototype.

Comment: Well I never put it together that actinium acetyl have the same abbreviation.

Answer (score 5):

Letter case in chemical **names** sometimes matters too! E.g. when ***o*-methylphenol** (*o*-cresol, *ortho*-cresol, 2-methylphenol, **I**) improperly capitalized to ***O*-methylphenol** (instead of *o*-Methylphenol), it can be interpreted as a different compound, phenol methylated at oxygen (anisole, methoxybenzene, **II**).

[image: Fig.1]